# Control Points in Canvas shape

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I have made canvas Shapes(squares) in kinetic js having 4 control points on each of their vertices.A user can click and drag these control points and distort the shape any way he/she pleases. I also tried adding control points in the mid-point of each line by adding additional anchors and plugging them into the Bezier Curve..The js fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/Lucy1/opsy1pn9/4/

The corresponding JS code is

```
   var room = new Kinetic.Shape({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: w,
    height: h,
    stroke: "blue",
    fill: 'red',
    drawFunc: function (context) {
        var x = this.x();
        var y = this.y();
        var w = this.width();
        var h = this.height();
        var tlX = this.anchorTL.x();
        var tlY = this.anchorTL.y();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(tlX, tlY);
        // top
        context.bezierCurveTo(x + w / 3, y, this.anchorTM.x(), this.anchorTM.y(), this.anchorTR.x(), this.anchorTR.y());
        // right
        context.bezierCurveTo(x + w, y + h / 3, this.anchorRM.x(), this.anchorRM.y(), this.anchorBR.x(), this.anchorBR.y());
        // bottom
        context.bezierCurveTo(x + w * 2 / 3, y + h, this.anchorBM.x(), this.anchorBM.y(), this.anchorBL.x(), this.anchorBL.y());
        // left
        context.bezierCurveTo(x, y + h * 2 / 3, this.anchorLM.x(), this.anchorLM.y(), tlX, tlY);

        context.closePath();
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    }
});

g.add(room);

room.anchorTR = makeAnchor(w, 0, g);
room.anchorBR = makeAnchor(w, h, g);
room.anchorBL = makeAnchor(0, h, g);
room.anchorTL = makeAnchor(0, 0, g);

room.anchorTM = makeAnchor(w/2,0,g);
room.anchorRM = makeAnchor(w,h/2,g);
room.anchorLM = makeAnchor(0,h/2,g);
room.anchorBM = makeAnchor(w/2,h,g);

layer.draw();
}
```

The problem i am facing is that the mid-point control points are not moving with the line like the control points situated at the vertex..Please Help.

Comment: You mean your issue is that the control points are not on the curve ? 
By definition, in Bezier curves the *control* points are outside the curve, hence their names. Only in the special case of a line the control point is on the curve.

Comment: ( Beware that your application has error, you seem to consider 4 corners will always form a rect. With this simplified version, handling the points is much more intuitive : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/opsy1pn9/5/  (i just have both bezier curve control points to be the middle anchor) )

Comment: In your js fiddle link the control points are outside the curve...any idea how to bring them on the curve like the vertex control points???

Comment: The mathematical question is : how to build the two control points of the bezier so that the middle anchor is on the resulting bezier curve. It is a bit of math... Hopefully a S.O. member will have an idea...

Comment: S.O. = Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking at the history of your posts, you have previously been using Cubic Bezier Curves.

**Each Bezier curve has 4 control points** so you need 4 anchors--not 3 as you show. The control points are: (1) starting point (a corner) (2) mid point influencing the starting point (3) mid point influencing the ending point (4) ending point (a corner).

But your fiddle uses just one control point on your curve between the corners. This indicates a Quadratic Curve instead of a Cubic Bezier Curve.

**Each Quadratic curve has 3 control points** so you need 3 anchors as in your fiddle. The control points are: (1) starting point (a corner) (2) middle control point influencing the curve (3) ending point (a corner).

So if instead you want the user to drag on a quadratic curve to manipulate that curve, you can approximate the resulting middle quadratic control point using this math:

```
var controlPointX = 2*mouseX -startpointX/2 -endpoinX/2;
var controlPointY = 2*mouseY -startpointY/2 -endpointY/2;
```

**Here's a Demo having the user drag to adjust a Quadratic curve:**

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/f4ag0myj/